# CallLog выдает не все данные

Tags: android, java

При выгрузке из журнала звонков в андроиде выдает только от 200 до 300 записей, несмотря на дату, если я сегодня сделаю 300 звонков, то и выдаст она только за сегодня:

```
        c = resolver.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
                CallLog.Calls.DATE, CallLog.Calls.DURATION,
                CallLog.Calls.CACHED_PHOTO_ID}, CallLog.Calls.TYPE + " = " + CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE, null, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
```

В чем дело или как это можно обойти, чтобы за раз взять все данные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте выбрать все.

```
Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);
```

Что в ответе приходит?

Comment: @nuclominus выдает 500, но туда входят и исходящие, а если запросить только с одним условием 

        c = resolver.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, CallLog.Calls.TYPE + " = " + CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE, null, null);

выдает также меньше 300.